# Interface implementation for VSTO Aplication.Factory class is missing methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interface, vsto, office-addins

I am reading C# code generated by the Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) framework, and have run into a case I don't understand.  I have simplified it as follows (I have omitted method parameters):

```
public interface Tools.Factory
{
    RibbonFactory GetRibbonFactory();   // OK
    AddIn CreateAddIn(...);                                         // Missing
    CustomTaskPaneCollection CreateCustomTaskPaneCollection(...);   // Missing
    SmartTagCollection CreateSmartTagCollection(...);               // Missing
}

public interface ApplicationFactory : Tools.Factory
{
    SmartTag CreateSmartTag(...);       // OK
    Action CreateAction(...);           // OK
    Document GetVstoObject(...);        // OK
    bool HasVstoObject(...);            // OK
}   

public ThisAddIn(ApplicationFactory factory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : 
        base(factory, serviceProvider, "AddIn", "ThisAddIn")
{
    Globals.Factory = factory;
}
```

The `ThisAddIn` constructor is code automatically generated by VSTO located in a designer.cs file.  It is passed an argument (`factory`) that implements the `ApplicationFactory` interface.  Using F12, I tracked down the interface as shown.  That interface in return inherits the `Tools.Factory` interface, which I have also listed.

What I don't understand: When I trigger IntelliSense in the editor for the `Globals.Factory` variable (shown below), I only see five out of the eight methods listed in the two interfaces (commented as OK in the code listing).  The implementations of three methods from the `Tools.Factory` interface are missing (commented as missing in the code listing).  Why is this?

[image]

Note: The code works fine.

Comment: Can you call the methods?  There are attributes that allow you to simply hide things from IntelliSense like `EditorBrowsable`.

Comment: @Zer0 You are right!  I am able to call the missing methods.  Please post as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @Zer0 In fact, the missing methods are marked `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`, which I completely ignored because I have never seen it before.  You are a damn genius. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are attributes such as `EditorBrowsable` that can hide methods and properties from both the designer and IntelliSense.

In this case the methods mentioned exist and can be called, but are hidden.